# Ms Sql convert varchar to Big Int

Tags: sql-server, varchar, bigint

I have Customer_Telephone_Number value in **varchar** in below side.

Customer_Telephone_Number value : **(222)-3333-333**

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE_1.dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE 
(
Customer_Telephone_Number
)

Select

CONVERT(BIGINT,Customer_Telephone_Number)

from 
DATABASE_2.DBO.CUSTOMER_TABLE
```

If ı try to insert Customer_Telephone_Number value to Database_1 , i get below exception.

```
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
```

**So how can i solve this problem or can i remove "(" and ")" to solve problem ?**

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know which exactly are the possible non numeric characters?

Comment: 1-(   )-222-2296
2-(332)-228-1180
3-(   )-   -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty way would be:

```
Select
    CONVERT
    (
        BIGINT,
        REPLACE
        (
            REPLACE
            (
                REPLACE
                (
                    REPLACE
                    (
                        Customer_Telephone_Number,
                        ' ',--Replace white spaces
                        ''
                    ),
                    '-',--Replace dashes
                    ''
                ),
                '(',--Replace open parenthesis
                ''
            ),
            ')',--Replace close parenthesis
            ''
        )
     )
from 
    DATABASE_2.DBO.CUSTOMER_TABLE
```

You can run the following in order to see other potential characters:

```
select Customer_Telephone_Number 
from DATABASE_2.DBO.CUSTOMER_TABLE
where ISNUMERIC
    (
        REPLACE
        (
            REPLACE
            (
                REPLACE
                (
                    REPLACE
                    (
                        Customer_Telephone_Number,
                        ' ',--Replace white spaces
                        ''
                    ),
                    '-',--Replace dashes
                    ''
                ),
                '(',--Replace open parenthesis
                ''
            ),
            ')',--Replace close parenthesis
            ''
        )
    ) = 0
```

This will give you a list of telephone numbers that cannot get converted to `BIGINT` . Check why (for instance if they have a `.` in them) and add these characters in the REPLACE as i did in the example.